# Incorrect day and year format after extracting "MM-DD-YYY" variable

Tags: r, string, date, extract

I am trying to generate day, month, and year variables based on the string values of a "date" variable, which is formatted as "27-02-2012" or "DD-MM-YYYY".

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(stringr)
library(textclean)
library(lubridate)
#library(zoo)
```

My variables are stored as follows:

```
sapply(data_corpus, class)
    post        date    username 
"character" "character" "character"
```

To extract and generate separate variables for day, month, and year, I ran this:

```
#Converting date variable
#data_corpus$date <- as_date(data_corpus$date)
```

But this turns all of my values in the "date" variable into NAs. So I also tried running this, which works well with month.

```
#Creating day, month, year variables 
data_corpus$day <- day(data_corpus$date)
data_corpus$month <- month(data_corpus$date)
data_corpus$year <- year(data_corpus$date)
```

However, a date like "27-02-2012" would
be extracted as follows, which means that month is extracted correctly, but "year" was extracted from the day values in the original "date" variable, and I am not sure how's the value for the "day" been generated?

```
   "date"        day   month    year
"27-02-2012"      20    2        27
```

Here is how the variables are stored after creating the 3 variables above:

```
sapply(data_corpus, class)
      post        date    username         day       month        year 
"character" "character" "character"   "integer"   "numeric"   "numeric"
```

Comment: As you are using lubridate, `data_corpus$date <- dmy(data_corpus$date)` or with `base R` `data_corpus$date <- as.Date(data_corpus$date, "%d-%m-%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
data_corpus$date <- dmy(data_corpus$date)
```

Or with `base R`

```
data_corpus$date <- as.Date(data_corpus$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```